# Showing specific post in order of array wp_query

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, query

I have displayed some specific post ID's in a custom template with wp_query.  I am struggling to figure out how to make these in order.  I want to show 1682 first and 1540 last.  They do not show this way and 'orderby'    => $successful_musics_array did not work for me.  How can one achieve this?

```
      <?php

      $successful_musics_array = array('1682', '1684', '556', '1793', '558', '1788', '320', '1190', '1865', '1125', '1863', '1540');

      $query = new WP_Query( array(
      'post_type' => 'songs',
      'posts_per_page' => '15',
      'post__in'      => $successful_musics_array
      ) );

        if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>


      <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'music-success' ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        <!-- show pagination here -->
    <?php else : ?>
        <!-- show 404 error here -->
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone struggling with this.  'orderby'=>'post__in' makes this work.

```
  <?php

  $successful_musics_array = array('1682', '1684', '556', '1793', '558', '1788', '320', '1190', '1865', '1125', '1863', '1540');

  $query = new WP_Query( array(
  'post_type' => 'songs',
  'posts_per_page' => '15',
  'post__in'      => $successful_musics_array,
  'orderby'=>'post__in'
  ) );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>


  <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'music-success' ); ?>

    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <!-- show pagination here -->
<?php else : ?>
    <!-- show 404 error here -->
<?php endif; ?>
```